# creating random question paper using probsoln package

Tags: exercises, random-numbers, probsoln

I have written code for generating random questions using Probson package. The only problem I face is that It shows the same output  again and again when I run the Program. What I want is whenver I run this program, It should select different questions from the files and give me different outputs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{probsoln}

\loadrandomproblems[easy1]{3}{file1.tex}%
\loadrandomproblems[easy2]{4}{file2.tex}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

 \foreachproblem[easy1]{\item \thisproblem}
  \foreachproblem[easy2]{\item \thisproblem}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

The contents of file1.tex are

```
\newproblem{dfp:xcube}{
Differentiate $f(x) = x^3$ with respect to $x$ by first principles.}{}

\newproblem{dfp:Ioverxsq}{
Differentiate $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ with respect to $x$ by first principles.}{}

\newproblem{dfp:sqrtx}{
Differentiate from first principles $f(x) = \surd x$}{}

\newproblem{dfp:cons}{
Differentiate from first principles $f(x) = c$ here $c$ is a constant.}{}

\newproblem{dfp:cosx1}{my next problem}{}
```

---

Contnets of file2.tex are

```
\newproblem{Q1}{first question}{}
\newproblem{Q2}{second question}{}
\newproblem{Q3}{third question}{}
\newproblem{Q4}{fourth question}{}
\newproblem{Q5}{five question}{}
\newproblem{Q6}{six question}{}
\newproblem{Q7}{seven question}{}
\newproblem{Q8}{eight question}{}
\newproblem{Q9}{nine question}{}
\newproblem{Q10}{Ten question}{}
```

Comment: With no experience in this package, my guess is that you will need supply a random number in each compilation, that is not created by default.  After giving a quick look at the documentation, `\PSNrandseed{\time}` seem one of the ways to do that, but I not tested it.

Comment: @Fran That's precisely it, please add an answer :-) The random number generator is actually deterministic, so two runs of the same code produce the same output. Providing a different seed with `\PSNrandseed` will change that initial state. Using `\time` ensures that the seed changes every minute of the day.

Comment: thanks i got the answer